# British novel about a group of high school teens who develop powers, and are taken abroad to be trained or experimented on

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I think this was a series.

What I remember is there is a group of high school teenagers who begin to develop powers. I believe they were experimented on in-vitro by a company, but I could be wrong.

The main character is a male who I believe develops telekinesis. I remember another character from the group develops the power of flight. I think this character had blonde hair.

I remember that the main character has a crush on another member of the group who is a female, but I can’t remember her power. I think in the book she is described as a popular ‘IT’ girl at school, and is very athletic.

I remember in one of the books, the group of kids end up being taken abroad, potentially Spain, to a facility to be trained or further experimented on??

I think I read the books between the years of 2010-2012 - if that’s of any help.

Comment: Maybe the [Seven Wonders series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_(series)).  Kids with special powers taken to an island.  First wonder is in Spain (I think) & allows the kids to fly.

Answer (score 4):

I think this book is *Edgewood* by Karen McQuestion (published in 2012).

Here is part of the blurb [from Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19033323-edgewood-series)

> Wandering the dark streets at night is Russ Becker's way of dealing with his relentless insomnia and the angst of life. But that changes forever the night he witnesses a strange astronomical event, then discovers he's developed incredible superpowers.
>
> And he's not alone. Three others in his town--sexy Mallory, arrogant Jameson, and mysterious Nadia--have had the same experience and acquired intriguing powers of their own. As if Mallory isn't special enough with her good looks and high IQ, now she can control peoples' minds. Jameson thinks he's the coolest because he moves objects with his thoughts, and shy Nadia struggles to understand her new empathic abilities.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the book (e.g. explain which details about your suggestion match the details in the question).

Answer (score 2):

The New Heroes, by *Irish* author Michael Carroll.
(known as "Quantum Prophecy" in the USA)

The **three protagonists** are:

- Colin, son of the two strongest in-universe heroes and inheritor of their combined powers.
  He has super strength. toughness, etc. and his story does indeed involve **learning to fly**.
- Danny, who has super-speed and intangibility. He suffers from **precognition** (not telekinesis) and is subjected to **experiments** because of it.
- Renata, who can become indestructible by transforming into some crystalline material. She got stuck in her crystal form, and remained a teenager while the world around her aged.

In the first book, Colin and Danny get abducted (Renata is stuck in crystal form, and is already in "bad guy" custody), and iirc, Colin does manage to escape in **Paris or Madrid** and gets help from kind strangers in pursuing the kidnappers.

Answer (score -1):

The medusa project by Sophie McKenzie

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in some info as to why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? A synopsis or any details that match from the original question?